# Database Create table Primary key not found

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables i'm trying to create with foreign keys.
The statements are below

Book_Copy Table

```
CREATE TABLE book_copy (
    bid          NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
    isbn         VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    firstavaib   VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    outservice   VARCHAR(9) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY ( bid,isbn ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( isbn )
        REFERENCES book_catalog ( isbn )
);
```

History table

```
CREATE TABLE history (
    bid          NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
    mid          NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ( mid )
        REFERENCES member ( mid ),
    datetaken    VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    datereturn   VARCHAR(9) NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ( bid )
        REFERENCES book_copy ( bid ),
    CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY ( bid, datetaken )
);
```

Now when I run it the first one says table created but i get the following for the second.

```
CREATE TABLE history (
    bid          NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
    mid          NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ( mid )
        REFERENCES member ( mid ),
    datetaken    VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    datereturn   VARCHAR(9) NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ( bid )
        REFERENCES book_copy ( bid ),
   CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY ( datetaken )
```

)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 *
ERROR at line 1:

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Comment: what db specifically

Comment: Oracle using sqlplus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in the statements above and also not all the relevant information was made available.

Your table `book_copy` has a foreign key reference to the table `book_catalog` via the `isbn` column:

```
CREATE TABLE book_copy (
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY ( isbn )
        REFERENCES book_catalog ( isbn )
```

To proceed, I took the liberty to add a simple one:

```
CREATE TABLE book_catalog (
    isbn VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_ct PRIMARY KEY (isbn));
```

And similar, they `history` table also references another table `member` via the `mid` column:

```
CREATE TABLE history (
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY ( mid )
        REFERENCES member ( mid ),
```

I also create that one in order to proceed:

```
CREATE TABLE MEMBER (
    mid NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_mem PRIMARY KEY (mid));
```

The error that you get above means what it says: There is no such primary key or unique key on the other table that you try to reference, hence a value cannot be uniquely identified and hence the integrity of the data not verified. So the database stops you from doing so in the first place.

The culprit is that you specify the `PRIMARY KEY` of your table `book_copy` to be `bid,isbn` while your foreign key reference in the `history` table only references the `bid`:

```
CREATE TABLE history (
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY ( bid )
        REFERENCES book_copy ( bid ),
```

So you ask the database to check the integrity on something that is not uniquely identifiable. In order to solve this you have to expand your foreign key of the history table to include the `isbn` column as well:

So the full DDL looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE book_catalog (
    isbn VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT book_catalog_pk PRIMARY KEY (isbn));

CREATE TABLE MEMBER (
    mid NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT member_pk PRIMARY KEY (mid));

CREATE TABLE book_copy (
    bid          NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
    isbn         VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    firstavaib   VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    outservice   VARCHAR(9) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT book_copy_pk PRIMARY KEY ( bid,isbn ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( isbn )
        REFERENCES book_catalog ( isbn )
);

CREATE TABLE history (
    bid          NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
    mid          NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    isbn         VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ( mid )
        REFERENCES member ( mid ),
    datetaken    VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    datereturn   VARCHAR(9) NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ( bid, isbn )
        REFERENCES book_copy ( bid, isbn ),
    CONSTRAINT history_pk PRIMARY KEY ( bid, datetaken )
);
```

There is another problem in your DDL above. In Oracle, constraint names are globally unique! That means that whatever you put after `CONSTRAINT` has to be unique. In the case above you use the same name `primary_key` for both your tables which will fail with an `ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint` error on creating the history table. You will see that I have given the primary key constraints on the tables more meaningful names.

Comment: Thank you my problem was that I was listing my Primary Keys from the Book_Copy table as two separate Foreign Keys in the History referencing the Book_Copy table, combined them into one Foreign Key statement and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Err: Foreign key(BID) references Book_Copy(BID)

The primary key of Book_Copy is (BID, DateTaken) not just (BID)

You need a primary or unique constraint in the target table referenced in a FK of another table.

1) Add DateTaken to you FK definition on HISTORY or replace the FK with a CHECK constraint something like (EXISTS (select * from book_copy c where c.BID = BID)